# Delete a Transcluded Element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I have a custom set of directives to effectively build a nestable navigation menu through the nav tag. I previously had some questions about how to get the contents of the transcluded text. While I have figured that out, **I now wonder if there is any way to delete a transcluded element so that it does not appears in the template afterwards**. [With This Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9su69j8vNygcyzPpHOZj?p=preview), you can see that the element is getting the text of the transcluded element. But it is still then included in the `ng-transclude` div.

You will be able to see the code in the plunker, but The corresponding piece of code in the plunker is :

```
//Other Code Here
controller:function($scope,$element,$attrs,$transclude){
        this.parents = [];

        var el = $transclude();

        if(angular.equals($attrs.menuTitle, undefined)) {
          $attrs.menuTitle= el.text().trim().split('\n')[0];
          el.remove(); //Runs, still leaves the transcluded element
        }





        this.addSubmenu = function(parent){

          this.parents.push(parent);
        };

      },
//Other Code Here
```

My knowledge of the `$transclude` value is minimal - the piece I got working here I just kind of stumbled upon through a lot of googling and checking questions on here.

I appreciate any help you can offer.

Comment: Just remove the `ng-transclude`?

Comment: It's the only way I've found to get the text, and these menus will be nested farther on down the road, so I am going to need the transclude.

Comment: What is the expected result? I'm understanding that you want to remove only the text element that you are using as the menuTitle, and leave the child directive to show as it is. Is that correct?

Comment: `<menu-item>Text</menu-item>` Should just have the text put in as the menuTitle attribute, the element that would be appended to the `<div>` in my template marked ng-transclude. That's all I want. I can work the rest of it out later; Just need to stop having the text show up in two places for right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the `ng-transclude` and do the transclution manually by using the `$transclude` function like this:

```
$transclude(function (clones) {
  if ($attrs.menuTitle === undefined) {
    $attrs.$set('menuTitle', clones.text().trim().split('\n')[0]);
  }

  var children = [];

  angular.forEach(clones, function (el) {
    // only transclude DOM node that you need here
    if (el.nodeName === 'PARENT' || el.nodeName === 'CHILD') {
      children.push(el);
    }
  })

  $element.find('div').append(children);        
});
```

**Example Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/jLvhzcX0uh1xQTTqtxXu?p=preview

Comment: You know I hadn't even thought about that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what that plunker **should** show if it is working, so it's hard to tell you how to achieve it.

Hopefully I can tell you a little more about transclude though.

Actually, if you want to have a bit more control over element transclusion, then you probably want to handle it in the `link` function, which has the following signature

```
link: function (scope, element, attributes, controller, transclude)
```

Then, inside your link function you can use the provided `transclude` function to do something with the element:

```
transclude(scope, function(clone, scope) {
  element.append(clone);
});
```

The first argument is the scope that you want the transcluded elements bound to.

**Side note**: the default functionality is a new (non-isolate) sub-scope of the controller in which the **transcluding** directive sits in. I.e. if you're using a directive with an isolate scope, then the transcluded content can't see it by default. You probably don't need to worry about this for this example though.

The second argument is a function, which takes the cloned element, and the new scope of that element. Inside this function you can append the `clone` to the directive's `element`, put it somewhere inside the template, before, or after, or just disregard it entirely.

Lastly, remember **`ng-transclude`** is a directive itself. Essentially `ng-transclude` is an out of the box implementation of the above (although it uses different a different scope as mentioned in the side note). As such, if you use the `transclude` function **and** you still have `ng-transclude` inside your template, then you will find two copies of the transcluded element. In other words, only use `ng-transclude` if you are not manually transcluding the content yourself.

Comment: Let me go and see if I can get that to work then, will update with what happens. **EDIT** Still gives me the same outcome. I get the text from the element and even though I call the remove method, nothing happens. I'm trying to avoid using a `compile()`, mostly because I don't understand it.